# ps -o cmd=<PID> Not Give Same Output From Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

From Python:

```
output = os.popen("ps -o cmd=1").read()
print output
```

Output:

```
1
/bin/bash
python myPython.pyc
sh -c ps -o cmd=1
ps -o cmd=1
```

But when I run that command from terminal it returns what I want:

```
/sbin/init
```

Also, when I run "ls -l" command from python, it returns correct thing.

---

My main purpose is finding name of process from its PID in Python.
What should I do ?

Comment: I'd note this in the python docs for `popen`  "Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the subprocess module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section."

Comment: I think a better approach to your goal would be to open and read `/proc/1/cmdline`. Either that or interpret the symbolic link `/proc/1/exe`.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I also tried subprocess but it gives same output.

Comment: @twalberg Oh "cat /proc/1/cmdline" works!

Please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not answer the question regarding why you get different output, but a better approach to solving the goal you are after is to either:

1. Open and read `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`, or
2. Read the symbolic link `/proc/<pid>/exe`

EDIT: Get rid of the `popen` call there and the subsequent "useless use of `cat`". Do this instead:

```
with open("/proc/"+data.get("pid")+"/cmdline") as cmd:
    cmdinfo=cmd.read()
command=cmdinfo.split("\0")
print command[0]
```

Comment: My code :

`print os.popen("cat /proc/"+data.get("pid")+"/cmdline").read()`

Comment: @furkant See the edit on getting rid of the deprecated `os.popen` and useless use of `cat`...

Comment: @furkantokac `os.popen("cat ...")` starts at least one, and maybe two completely new processes (one for "/usr/bin/cat" and possibly one for a shell - i.e. what may actually get run is something like `/usr/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/cat ..."`), which is considerably less efficient than just calling the standard library functions to open and read the file in your current process. Especially since all you're doing is reading the exact contents of the file, not filtering or transforming it in any way (which for most cases would still be more efficiently done with native Python code).

Answer (score 1):

I know you have an answer now, but the reason that your original attempt did not work is probably because popen creates a brand new process, and therefore a different process environment.

When I run 'ps -o cmd=1' from my Terminal, I get similar results as you did when you used popen.

```
1
bash
ps -o cmd=1
```